# UPDATE TABLE returning empty values when querying with variable

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a table with the columns 'id', 'title', 'name' and am trying to insert values into it based on parsed XML with Beautiful Soup. The function to keep track of where each value goes is defined by:

```
def getmax(column):
    query = 'select count(?) from table'
    c.execute(query, [column])
    result = c.fetchall()
    for e, i in enumerate(result):
        for y in enumerate(i):
            if not y[1]:
                return 0
            else:
                return y[1] # used because fetchall returns a tuple
```

which gives me the last row where a value was inserted for each column. The function to insert values looks like:

```
for e in soup.findAll('title'):
    e = str(e)
    query = "insert into table (id, title) values (?, ?)"
        c.execute(query, (getmax('title') + 1, e))
        db.commit()
for e in soup.findAll('name'):
    e = str(e)
    query = "UPDATE table SET name = (?) WHERE id = (?);"
    c.execute(query, (e, getmax('name') + 1))
    db.commit()
```

This returns:

```
id    title    name 

1     title1
2     title2
3     title3
4     title4
5     title5
```

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `format()` (see [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3) for more info) method to solve this problem. In addition, you can use the `a if condition else b` in order to simplify your code:

```
def getmax(column):
    query = 'select count({}) from longform'.format(column)
    c.execute(query)
    result = c.fetchall()
    for e, i in enumerate(result):
        for y in enumerate(i):
            return y[1] if y[1] else 0
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea why that (and my solution) solve it while the first method I tried didn't? I looked into it more and for some reason that first method was miscounting the number of values in each row.

Comment: @snapcrack, not really sure, but as far as I know you should avoid using `?`  on table or column names. Optionally you can use the concatenation operator `"+"`, but I prefer to use the `format` function in general.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a problem with the way variables are handled in Python. Strangely,  replacing the `(?)` with `%s` fixed it. So this:

```
def getmax(column):
    query = 'select count(%s) from longform' % column
    c.execute(query)
    result = c.fetchall()
    for e, i in enumerate(result):
        for y in enumerate(i):
            if not y[1]:
                return 0
            else:
                return y[1]
```

works, while the version of `getmax` posted in the question doesn't. Would be curious to know why.